# sort a file based on length of chars in the first column/row

Tags: linux, sorting, sed, awk, grep

I need to sort a file based on the number of chars in the first column.

I have no idea on how to go about this. I'm using Linux, so sed/awk/sort are all available.

```
.abs is bla bla 12 
.abc is bla se 23 bla
.fe is bla bla bla
.jpg is pic extension
.se is for swedish domains
```

What I want is to sort these lines, based on the length of the first column in each line.
Some of the lines start with 4 characters, some start with 3, or 2. I want the result to be something like:

```
.fe is bla bla bla 
.se is for swedish domains 
.abs is bla bla 12 
.abc is bla se 23 bla 
.jpg is pic extension
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: for the lines with same length (column1), how would you sort them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Augment each line by the length of the first word, then sort:

```
awk '{ print length($1) " " $0; }' $FILE | sort -n
```

If necessary, cut out the helper field with `cut -d ' ' -f 2-` afterwards.

Comment: @Instronics: You're welcome, and welcome on SO. Accepting a working answer is the common way of saying Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

or you can also use sed afterwards like this

`awk '{print length($1)" "$0}' temp.txt | sort -k 1,2| sed -re 's/^[0-9]+ //'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with coreutils, albeit rather inefficient:

```
paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 infile | xargs -l sh -c 'echo "$1" | wc -c' '{}') infile |
  sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Or with GNU parallel if it is available:

```
paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 infile | parallel wc -c '<<< {}') infile | 
  sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Or with bash:

```
<infile while read c1 rest; do echo ${#c1} "$c1" "$rest"; done |
  sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```